# How to specify environment variables without expansion in gyp files?

Tags: gyp

I want to specify an `rpath`, like this:

```
'ldflags': [
  '-rpath', '/usr/$LIB/myprog',
],
```

But when I check the resulting binary, I see it has another `rpath`:

```
$ objdump -x binary | grep RPATH
  RPATH                /usr//myprog:$ORIGIN/lib/
```

What I want is: `/usr/$LIB/myprog:...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one should do the following:

```
'ldflags': [
  '-rpath', '/usr/\$$LIB/myprog',
],
```